# Creating tables and relationships from csv files

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I want to create simple MySQL tables from csv files. How do I do this? I am using MySQL Workbench (I just started learning SQL and MySQL).

Here are what my csv files look like:

**foo.csv**: 1 column (header="`foo_id`") and 50,000+ rows. `foo_ids` are strings (less than 25 characters)

```
foo_id
foo_1
foo_2
foo_3
foo_4
...
...
...
```

**bar.csv**: 1 column (header="`bar_id`") and 100,000+ rows. `bar_ids` are strings (less than 25 characters)

```
bar_id
bar_1
bar_2
bar_3
bar_4
...
...
...
```

**foo_to_bar.csv**: 2 columns (headers="`foo_id`", "`bar_id`") and 70,000+ rows. `foo_ids` and `bar_ids` are strings. Assume not all `foo_ids` and `bar_ids` from `foo.csv` and `bar.csv` are in `foo_to_bar.csv`

```
foo_id bar_id
foo_1  bar_2
foo_1  bar_3
foo_3  bar_4
foo_4  bar_5
foo_4  bar_6
foo_4  bar_7
...    ...
...    ...
...    ...
```

From these csv files, I'd like to create a `foo` table and `bar` table. The `foo` table contains all `foo_ids`. Since `foo_ids` are strings, perhaps it's a good idea to also add a auto incremental `primary_key` column for each `foo_id` as an integer.

```
primary_key foo_id
1           foo_1
2           foo_2
3           foo_3
...         ...
...         ...
...         ...
```

The `bar` table should be similar to the `foo` table, but with an additional column labeled as `foo_id`. I would like `foo_ids` and `bar_ids` in a one to many mappings relationship, where one `foo_id` can map to 0, 1, or more `bar_ids`.

```
primary_key bar_id foo_id
1           bar_1  
2           bar_2  foo_1 (Should this display 'foo_1' or its primary key (1)?)
3           bar_3  foo_1
4           bar_4  foo_3
5           bar_5  foo_4
...         ...    ...
...         ...    ...
...         ...    ...
```

Also, with these tables, would I be able to get the `bar_ids` from a given `foo_id` as well as find the `foo_id` of a given `bar_id`?

EDIT: I am currently using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to make 3 tables from 3 csv files. Is this the right approach so far?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Sablefoste No. I currently have a program that parses through these csv  files, but would like to use a database like MySQL instead.

Comment: Have you considered creating the tables in MySQL first, and then using something like PHPMYADMIN to import the CSV files?  Then you can manipulate the data all you want with normal SQL.

Comment: @Sablefoste No, PHPMYADMIN is a new term for me. I think I am having a hard time figuring out how to to populate the `bar` table using both `bar.csv` and `foo_to_bar.csv`.

Comment: I am also having trouble using the import button feature in MySQL workbench. Everytime I try to import one of my csv files, the application becomes unresponsive. Are my csv files too large to handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can get csv to sql converters online with a quick google search.

It has also been mentioned that you can use PhpMyAdmin or other similar sofware to import Csv files to easily managable tables. This requires access to either a webserver or a localhost which is a bit of effort to set up just for a few queries.

Either of the above options make it simple enough to parse CSV files to SQL.

EDIT:

Take the converted CSV file and open it in a text editor. You will see:

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable(
    filed1        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,field2          NUMERIC(16,11) NOT NULL
    ,field3 INTEGER  NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO mytable(field1,filed2,field3) VALUES (1,2,3);
    INSERT INTO mytable(field1,filed2,field3) VALUES (4,5,6);
    INSERT INTO mytable(field1,filed2,field3) VALUES (7,8,9);
 etc
```

Change this to:

```
    INSERT INTO mytable
       (filed1,field2,field3)
    VALUES
       (1,2,3),
       (4,5,6),
       (7,8,9);
    etc
```

If you have a ton of entries use find and replace function to save yourself some typing...

Comment: The online sql converters give me a sql script with many INSERT statements. I try running the script but it takes a very long time to complete (script has 50,000+ INSERT statements). I've tried using the import feature using MySQL Workbench, but the application becomes unresponsive whenever I try importing any of my csv files.

Comment: Yes most of them will give an insert for each line.

You are getting:
INSERT INTO mytable(value, value value);
INSERT INTO mytable(value, value, value): and so on.

You can replace this with:
A single INSERT INTO mytable(valuename,valuename,valuename);
VALUES (value,value,value):
(value,value,value)

Comment: So if I have a bunch of csv files I want to put into a MySQL database, would the approach be to convert each csv file into SQL scripts? I fear this may take a very long time. A single csv file under 2 MB takes me 10+ minutes.

Comment: See my edit, this should save you a whole lot of time :)

use find and replace in a word processer to change "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES" to a comma ''," and then add your INSERT INTO with the fields at the top.